# push a new git repo up to a server without --bare

Tags: git

I know how to create a bare repo on a server for pulling/pushing etc., but the repo I'd like to push to the server now is for a website, so I don't want to create a bare repo.

I want to be able to make changes in my local repo (aka on my computer), push them, and have them be reflected in the website right away, without having to log onto the server and pull them into the working directory.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this straight into the same git checkout that's hosting your website, no, but you could set up a post-commit hook that triggers some other system to update the website on the server from your git repository (which can be bare or not). This is usually called "continuous deployment".

Comment: @VonC (below) showed me how to do the hook, and it works. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so I don't want to create a bare repo.

I would still advise to create a bare repo.

And then, still on the server, *clone* that bare repo to the actual folder "`myFolder`" which will be served.

```
git clone /path/to/bare/repo.git /path/to/myFolder
```

(the `.git` in `repo.git` is a naming convention to designate a bare repository root folder)

In `/path/to/bare/repo.git/hooks`, add a `post-receive` executable file (no extension), which will cd (change directory) to the non-bare repo, and pull from the bare:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
cd /path/to/checkout/repository
git pull
git checkout -f
```

Comment: And this will run automatically?

Comment: I tested it. It does. Thanks! How is this different from pre-receive, by the way?

Comment: @AlGorithm Yes, it is run automatically, once the push has completed. Sorry for the delay: I was sleeping.

Comment: @AlGorithm The difference with pre-receive is that you need the content to be updated in order to checkout it. And during the pre-receive hook, the content has not yet been fully updated.